# How to speed up JavaParser

Tags: java, javaparser

I'm using **JavaParser v3.13.5** to build AST from an expressions. I have spotted that parsing expression even simple like `Objects.equals(a, b)` takes up too much time (~0.15 s). Are there any options, besides `ParserConfiguration`, to speed up parsing?

**EDIT**

Code to reproduce results:

```
JavaParser javaParser = new JavaParser(
        new ParserConfiguration()
                .setStoreTokens(false)
                .setAttributeComments(false)
                .setDoNotAssignCommentsPrecedingEmptyLines(true)
                .setIgnoreAnnotationsWhenAttributingComments(true)
                .setLexicalPreservationEnabled(true)
                .setPreprocessUnicodeEscapes(false)
                .setLanguageLevel(LanguageLevel.RAW)
                .setCharacterEncoding(Providers.UTF8));

String strExpr = "Objects.equals(a, b)";

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//Expression expr = StaticJavaParser.parseExpression(strExpr); // even slower...
ParseResult<Expression> parseResult = javaParser.parseExpression(strExpr); // slow...
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println((double) (end-start)/1000);
```

Is there any method which can be overriden to suppress some unnecessary validations or something else?

Comment: you could upgrade your hardware

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Sure, hardware upgrade always solve performance issues, but it is always the last option, which I'm not looking for.

Comment: mybe it helps to parse as input stream oO or using the .parse method (ive seen that example a lot omore often)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually (JP version 3.16.3) takes 2983.4 nano seconds to parse this statement.

```
 String code = "Objects.equals(a, b);";
 long start = System.nanoTime();
 Statement stmt = StaticJavaParser.parseStatement(code);
 long end = System.nanoTime();
 System.out.println((double) (end-start)/1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can disable LexicalPreservation which is not used in your example.